# Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $f(x,y):=(x-y^2)(x-2y^2)$. Show that $\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \exists z\in B_\varepsilon (0) : f(z)<f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $f(x,y):=(x-y^2)(x-2y^2)$. Show that
>   $\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \exists z\in B_\varepsilon (0) : f(z)<f(0)$

What even is $f(0)$ if we have two variables? Or it a typo? Because $\nabla f(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y=0$

Comment: Note that your text (or professor) also wrote $B_\varepsilon(0)$, so $0$ there clearly indicates the origin, as it does with $f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

I understand $z$ as being $(x,y)$ and $0$ as being $(0,0)$ ;

In this way $f(0)=0$ has to be understood in the following way : on the left hand side $0=(0,0)$ and on the right hand side $0$ is number $0$.

As the given expression can be written

$$(x-\tfrac32 y^2)^2-\tfrac14y^4 \tag{1}$$

therefore it suffices to take $z=(0,\varepsilon)$ to get a negative value for the result of $(1)$.

Comment: Do you mean $z=(0,\varepsilon)$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic yes, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: The product of two real numbers is negative when one is positive and the other is negative.

Comment: Well, $(x-y^2)(x-2y^2)<0 \Leftrightarrow \left( x>0 \, \land -\sqrt{x}<y<-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\vee \left( x>0  \, \land \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}}<y<\sqrt{x}\right)$

Comment: It's probably easier just to think in terms of where $x$ is, rather than solving for $y$.